# How to transform a data frame in spark structured streaming using python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am testing structured streaming using localhost from which it reads a stream of data. Input streaming data from localhost:

```
ID   Subject  Marks
--------------------
1    Maths    85  
1    Physics  80  
2    Maths    70  
2    Physics  80
```

I would like to get the average marks for each unique ID's.

I tried this but not able to transform the DF which is a single value.

Below is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *  
from pyspark.sql.types import *
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SrteamingAge").getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField("ID", IntegerType(), \  
True),StructField("Subject", StringType(), True),StructField("Marks", \
IntegerType(), True)])

marks = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", 
"localhost").option("port", 9999).schema(schema).load()
marks.printSchema()
result = marks.groupBy("ID").agg(avg("Marks").alias("Average Marks"))
```

But I am getting the below error:

```
    root
      |-- value: string (nullable = true)

Pyspark.sql.utils.Analysisexception: "u can not resolve 'ID' given input columns: [value];"
```

I am creating a schema for the same but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

My expected output is just 2 columns (ID and Average Marks)

```
ID  Average Marks  
1     82.5  
2     75
```

Comment: Avg Mark is better than Avg Marks. Can you show some more code? There are various output modes to consider.

Comment: Here's what you want to do: 
```marks.groupBy("ID").agg(avg("Marks").as("Average Marks"))```
But this won't work because looking at your schema, the column type is string. Take a look at the code example here on how you can convert the stream of strings into dataframe with required schema: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#creating-streaming-dataframes-and-streaming-datasets

Comment: I have update my code above but no luck with it. @HarichandanPulagam

Comment: The problem is your dataframe has no column named ID, but you are trying to group on it. You need to split the column named "value" like so: `df = marks.withColumn("value", split(col("value"), "\\,")).select(col("value").getItem(0).cast("int").alias("ID"), col("value").getItem(1).alias("Subject"), col("value").getItem(2).cast("int").alias("Marks")).drop("value")
`, and then group on `df`, assuming you input it `1,Maths,85` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe has no column named ID, but you are trying to group on it. You need to split the column named "value" like so:

```py
df = marks\
  .withColumn("value", split(col("value"),"\\,"))  \
  .select(
    col("value").getItem(0).cast("int").alias("ID"),
    col("value").getItem(1).alias("Subject"),
    col("value").getItem(2).cast("int").alias("Marks")) \
  .drop("value")
```

Then group on df:

```py
result = df.groupBy("ID").agg(avg("Marks").as("Average Marks"))
```

Assumption: Input is of the form `1,Maths,85` and so on